# SUMIF case when SQL - sum based on row value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sum, case

I have a data set with cols A, B, C. I want to sum C where the value in B is >= than the rest of the values in B. I have tried a Sum with a case when but can't seem to get the condition to use the row value. Any ideas?

Input:

```
A|B|C
1|1|1
1|2|1
1|3|1
2|1|0
2|2|1
2|3|0
```

wanted output:

```
A|B|C|Output
1|1|1|3
1|2|1|2
1|3|1|1
2|1|0|1
2|2|1|1
2|3|0|0
```

Code tried but does not work due to condition

```
SUM(case when B>=B then C end) over(partition by A) as Output
```

---

Output calculation:

```
A|B|C|Output calculation                                  |Excel calculation                | Output 
1|1|1|Sum all values in Col C where values in B>=1 and A=1 | =SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,">="&B2,A:A,A2) |=3
1|2|1|Sum all values in Col C where values in B>=2 and A=1 | =SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,">="&B3,A:A,A3) |=2
1|3|1|Sum all values in Col C where values in B>=3 and A=1 | =SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,">="&B4,A:A,A4) |=1
2|1|0|Sum all values in Col C if values in B>=1 and A=2    | =SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,">="&B5,A:A,A5) |=1
2|2|1|Sum all values in Col C if values in B>=2 and A=2    | =SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,">="&B6,A:A,A6) |=1
2|3|0|Sum all values in Col C if values in B>=3 and A=2    | =SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,">="&B7,A:A,A7) |=0
```

Comment: Are you using Bigquery or T-SQL? I've removed the conflicting tags for now

Comment: What are the "rest of the values"?  It is not at all clear (to me) how your output is calculated.  Perhaps you could show that detail.

Comment: "rest of the values" = all values in col B

Comment: Have added excel formula that might help explain a bit more - hope it helps

Comment: @16143 "rest of the values" = all values in col B  , means calculate sum(c) only if b = max(b)

Comment: @eshirvana no, it means sum(c) only if the value in col b is greater than the value in col B for that row - a bit hard to explain! the excel formula hopefully shows the condition to sum is based on the value of B in the row

Comment: @16143 - Is the composite key of `A, B` unique in the source table?

Comment: the output doesn't match the calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need a self-join or correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(t2.c)
        from t t2
        where t2.a = t.a and t2.b > t.b
       ) as output
from t;
```

Your logic might be equivalent to a reverse sum on `c` by the `b` values:

```
select t.*,
       sum(c) over (partition by a order by b desc)
from t;
```

However, I'm not sure how you want to handle rows with the same `b` value.

Comment: what would t2 be in the top query?

Comment: @16143 - Where the correlated sub-query has `FROM t t2` it's a second reference to the table `t`, given the alias `t2`, so that the two instances can be referred to separately.  Much like a self join of `t AS t1 INNER JOIN t AS t2` *(where the `AS` is optional, and therefore implicit in this answer's code)*

Comment: Great! thanks! the where caluse in the top query lets you control the condition which is what I needed. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Consider below approach

```
select *,
  sum(c) over(partition by a order by b desc) output
from data
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Meantime, I noticed some discrepancies with thin the question related to how to handle B=B case, in excel formula it says  `where values in B>...` while in output example and code tried it is `when B>=B then` and so far it is what all currently provided answers do.
So, below "does" `B>B` logic (and can be easily modified to any lag value)

```
select *,
  sum(c) over(partition by a order by b range between 1 following and unbounded following) output
from data
```

with output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> select * , sum(C) over (partition by A order by B desc)
> from data
> order by A,B
> ```
>
> ```
>  a |  b |  c | sum
> -: | -: | -: | --:
>  1 |  1 |  1 |   3
>  1 |  2 |  1 |   2
>  1 |  3 |  1 |   1
>  2 |  1 |  0 |   1
>  2 |  2 |  1 |   1
>  2 |  3 |  0 |   0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a0dc84d81b1c03947754e0cc3fbb507a)*